# How do you multiply algebraic expressions or matrices with more than 3 variables?

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus, associativity

How do you multiply expressions that have more than 3 variables?

For example, how would you multiply:

- $a \cdot b \cdot c \cdot d $

if associativity only defines the multiplication of 3 variables?
ie. $(ab)c = a(bc)$

The same goes for matrices. How would you multiply:

- $A \cdot B \cdot C \cdot D$

If associativity only allows for the multiplication of 3 matrices?
ie. $(AB)C = A(BC)$

This is something that I had never thought of (I am currently in high school) until recently and it is really problematic for me. Any insight into this would be appreciated.

Comment: The definition of associativity is stated only for three factors, because more factors follows from this.  A good exercise is to formulate this properly, then prove it by induction on the number of factors.

Comment: Can you provide an example, of proving it by induction?

Comment: Draw a picture of how the multiplications happen. Put a dot for each of the factors then if you are multiplying two pieces make a new dot for the resulting piece below the rest and draw arrows from the new dot to the dots for those two pieces. What does it look like?

Answer (score 2):

We want to show $a(bcd)=(abc)d$. Notice that, if I were to write $bc=e$, then we can reduce it to associativity of $3$ variables as follows:

$a(bcd)=a(ed)=(ae)d$ (by associativity on $3$ variables).

But then putting back $bc=e$, we get $a(bcd)=(abc)d$. Thus we have shown associativity on $4$ variables.

Do you see how a similar argument would give us associativity on $5, 6, 7, \dots$ variables?

Basically, if multiplication of something (whether that's real numbers, matrices, or anything else you might encounter) is shown to be associative on $3$ variables, then you deduce that is is on any string of variables. We can thus forget about brackets, and write, for example, $abcde$ for any of

$$a(bcde) =ab(cd)e = a(bc)(de) = \dots$$

since we know these will just all be the same.

Note that there are [weirder mathematical objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion) out there where associativity does not hold, and brackets are important. Nothing you'd meet in a high school course would have this property though, so don't worry about associativity for now.